# ObjectiveFlickr Photo Upload Error

Tags: iphone, ios, flickr, photo-upload

I'm working on using the ObjectiveFlickr library to upload photos to Flickr from my iPhone app.  I am able to authorize the app and perform general requests, but I am getting an error while trying to upload a photo. The photo is meant to be uploaded is an image captured using AVFoundation.  Here is the relevant code:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
if ([[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].apiContext.OAuthToken length]) {
                    NSData *uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

                   if (!flickrRequest) {
                        flickrRequest = [[OFFlickrAPIRequest alloc] initWithAPIContext:[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].apiContext];
                        flickrRequest.delegate = self;
                        flickrRequest.requestTimeoutInterval = 60.0;
                    }

                    [flickrRequest uploadImageStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:uploadData] suggestedFilename:@"Test" MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0", @"is_public", nil]];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;

                    NSLog(@"Can upload photo");
```

The `flickrRequest` object is defined and `@property`'d in the .h file pertaining to the code above.

The `OFFlickrRequestDelegate` methods are as follows:

```
- (void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest imageUploadSentBytes:(NSUInteger)inSentBytes totalBytes:(NSUInteger)inTotalBytes {
    NSLog(@"Success");
}

- (void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest didCompleteWithResponse:(NSDictionary *)inResponseDictionary {
    NSLog(@"%s %@ %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, inRequest.sessionInfo, inResponseDictionary);
}

- (void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest didFailWithError:(NSError *)inError {
    NSLog(@"%s %@ %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, inRequest.sessionInfo, inError);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[inError description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

When I run the project on the device the console shows:

```
Can upload photo
Success
Success
Success
Success
flickrAPIRequest:didFailWithError:(null) Error Domain=org.lukhnos.ObjectiveFlickr Code=2147418115 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (org.lukhnos.ObjectiveFlickr error 2147418115.)"
```

Searching through the API's documentation, "error `2147418115`" is defined as "`OFFlickrAPIRequestFaultyXMLResponseError`". I'm not really sure what this means though. Also strange--"Success" appears four times when I'm only attempting to upload one photo.

The sample app utilizing ObjectiveFlickr, "Snap and Run" uploads photos fine on the same device that I am testing on. Comparing the code between my app and Snap and Run, I don't see any major differences that could cause the photo not to upload.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange. `OFFlickrAPIRequestFaultyXMLResponseError` means the returned data cannot be parsed as XML. If the sample app SnapAndRun runs correctly and yours don't, I suggest add one line in ObjectiveFlickr.m, right after the line `NSString *stat = [rsp objectForKey:@"stat"];`:

```
NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request receivedData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"received response: %@", dataString);
```

This may help you find out what goes wrong (e.g. if it's a server-side issue, or some response format that the library missed).

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error I used [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see what was going on. Flickr was sending back an error saying that the signature was invalid. Looking at my request, I found that I had reversed the order of the key and values (i.e. there was whitespace in one of my keys, which probably caused a signature error).