# Error while uploading image to flickr in iphone(Xcode 4.2)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app, I want to share an image to flickr.
I used the libraries provided by flickr. After authorization I call the following method

```
[self.flickrRequest uploadImageStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:JPEGData] suggestedFilename:@"Pic 2 Print" MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0", @"is_public", nil]];
```

but I get this error

> kUploadImageStep Error Domain=org.lukhnos.ObjectiveFlickr
>   Code=2147418115 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (org.lukhnos.ObjectiveFlickr error 2147418115.)

If anyone knows then plz help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I resolved upload image issue. But now the image is uploaded on flickr but still gives this error but only some times not at all. & gives same error as above.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691566/objectiveflickr-photo-upload-error

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was with the default user agent the lib is using. It seems like Flickr is blocking connections from iOS. When I put a different user agent, `HTTPRequest.userAgent = @"hehe";` I got it working.